# How to create a json file in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

According to following fields:

```
url ="blewpass.com"
ssl = "yes"
tags = [{'html':'hi'},{'title':'My first page'},{'h2':'My First Line'},{'p':'Hey'},{'h2':'My Second Line'}]
```

I want to convert these fields into JSON format and store it in a JSON file. I cannot convert the tags into a single dictionary, because the key cannot hold many values. So,  I want to convert these fields directly into JSON? How to create a properly managed json data format from these fields?

Comment: Google or the search field above were no help?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: what will be expected output? only tags you want in JSON ? if yes try `json.dumps(tags)`

Comment: "I cannot convert the tags into a single dictionary, because the key cannot hold many values" This doesn't make any sense. You clearly know what a list is, because you are already using them. It also doesn't make sense because *JSON has the same limitation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to write all the fields to the json file,

Try

```
import json

url ="blewpass.com"
ssl = "yes"
tags = [{'html':'hi'},{'title':'My first page'},{'h2':'My First Line'},{'p':'Hey'},{'h2':'My Second Line'}]

temp_json = tags
temp_json.insert(0,({"url":url,"ssl":ssl}))

file = open("filename.json",'w')

json.dump(temp_json,file)
```

Comment: not only tags, all three fields into a single json file